# Angular 6.x Typescript errors - cannot find name 'Map' or 'Iterable'

Tags: typescript, angular6

Not sure why Im getting these errors now.  Seems its type and typescript related.  Some of these errors are coming from node_modules\@angular\core\src\di\reflective_provider.d.ts

```
Error   TS2304  (TS) Cannot find name 'Iterable'.   node_modules\@angular\core\src\change_detection\differs\default_iterable_differ.d.ts    12  Active


Error   TS2304  (TS) Cannot find name 'Map'.    node_modules\@angular\core\src\change_detection\differs\default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts    24  Active
```

Here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es5",   
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": ["es5", "es6", "dom"]
  }
}
```

Upgraded ts to 3.1.3 latest.
devDependencies from package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.7",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "3.1.3"
  }
```

**I found the fix.**
One of the Typescript files I had somehow the BuildAction was set to "TypeScript" which will have VS doing the build.  However, since Im using VS 2017 and Angular6 with a cli project, the build options are handled via Angular CLI
Seen this suggestion on a Github post here
https://github.com/aspnet/templating/issues/459

Comment: Are u using rxjs in Services??? I used to get such errors when I used map in services and haven't  imported it

Comment: Angular 6.0.7 doesn't support TypeScript 3.1.3.

Comment: Yes, I switched back to 2.9.2, but see update at the bottom of the first post.  The build option flag on one particular file was the culprit at least for my case.